# Populate silverlight grid from a text file

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, grid, readfile

Friends,
I have a requirement i am given a text file with fixed no. of columns but row varies, i should read that and populate that in grid/table using Silverlight
The text file will have data something like this

0, 0, 2, 1, "url1", description1
1, 0, 2, 2, "url2", description2
1, 1, 4, 2, "url3", description2

as we can see columns are fixed but row can vary

Now i want my silverlight app to read this file from system and populate in grid/table like

RowNo ColumnNo Width Height    ImageURL    Description
0   0   2   1   url1       Description1
1   0   2   2   url2       Description2
1   1   4   2   url3       Description3

I tried reading file using 
Streamreader but its showing SecurityException error 'SecurityExceptionHandler was unhandled by user code
File operation not permitted. Access to path 'c:\path\file.txt' is denied.

Hope my question is clear

Please help me out
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 13 views, no answer yet? Friends please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show an [OpenFileDialog and create a StreamReader from it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Use StreamReader.ReadLine() to read it line by line. String.Split(',') to get the columns or use a more sophisticated regex if the columns can contain commas within their quotes.

That's as far as I can help you. Haven't used DataGrid, but the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for it look unusually detailed and its interface very simple.

Comment: Out-of-Browser? good but i m new to silverlight and programming, can you explain me with an example please.

Comment: Google it. But I forgot you can also just use OpenFileDialog. I edited my answer.